# Is there anything to perform union of two lists in Erlang?

Tags: list, set, erlang, erlang-shell, set-operations

I found out that there are set operations for sets in Erlang, but I could not find out similar operations for lists. I want to perform the basic union operation in lists in Erlang:

```erlang
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [1, 2, 5]
C = A union B = [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

How can I perform this operation in Erlang?

I did the following using sets, though, and it works. I was just wondering, if I can do this without sets.

```erlang
C = sets:to_list(sets:union(sets:from_list(A),sets:from_list(B))).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate the two lists and then sort them, removing duplicates:

```
A = [1, 2, 3],
B = [1, 2, 5],
C = lists:usort(A ++ B).
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great!!

Answer (score 2):

The `ordsets` module handles ordered lists as sets, using the same API as the `sets` module. https://erlang.org/doc/man/ordsets.html